# Is there a way to determine/guess the OpenCL platforms on my system without using one?

Tags: command-line, opencl

One can determine which OpenCL platforms are available on a system using the OpenCL API function `clGetPlatformIDs()`, and then get information about each platform using `clGetPlatformInfo()` etc. However - in order for that to happen, one needs to compile against `libOpenCL`.

Can one determine such information, on a GNU/Linux system, by merely inspecting the filesystem somehow? e.g. from a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the OpenCL platforms' `.icd` files under `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/`. However - this in itself isn't enough:

- Some ICDs may not correspond to a usable/visible OpenCL platform.
- The ICD files don't tell you the full platform name
- It's not clear how, if at all, it's possible to determine platform indices from ICD files.